# Strange effect of History.pushState method in Chromium-based browser with Angular SPA

Tags: angular, firefox

English isn't my native, so... you know... :)

Our Angular application uses 3rd-party code, which at some point executes code `window.history.pushState({...}, "", "")`. In a Chromium-based browser, this code results in removing the path part from the URL, leaving only the origin part. So, if the code was executed on `https://example.com/news/123456`, the URL changed to `https://example.com`. But we don't observe this behavior in Firefox, the URL doesn't change after `pushState(...)`. Without a third argument (`new URL`) code works as expected - don't change the URL - in both browsers.

So, I tried to find, maybe the Angular override method `pushState()`, but didn't find anything. We use the "outdated" version of Angular (9.1.12), so I wanted to check this behavior on the "newer" version. I opened `https://angular.io/api/common/Location` in Chrome and Firefox and ran `window.history.pushState({_: 1}, "", "")` in their console. As a result, I have `https://angular.io` in Chrome and `https://angular.io/api/common/Location` in Firefox. Just to be sure, I repeated this experiment with a non-Angular site - maybe it's browser-related behavior - for example, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular`: in both browsers URL doesn't change.

Is this a bug, so I need to open an issue on Angular's git? Is this behavior correct, then why it's inconsistent in different browsers?

Any ideas? :)

Versions of browsers:

- Firefox 102.0 (64-bit)
- Chrome 118.0.5993.70 (64-bit)

Comment: Firefox doesn't change the URL at all when pushing state of "".  If you instead used "?test" for the 3rd param, you'd see the same behavior as Chrome, though.  It would append "?test" to the root URL on an angular page.  Why it's different for a URL to an Angular page I don't understand though.  Somehow it knows the difference between the served page and it's parameters.

Comment: after some more testing, I believe this is because of the <base href> tag that Angular apps will all define: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base  If absent, location.href is used.

Comment: Hmm, I kind of forgot about the `document.baseURI`, we already had problems with it while using links with anchors. Thank you, @pcalkins, for guiding me in the right direction. So, I'm off to RTFM :). It looks like this issue is more of a Firefox bug, so I'll add a "Firefox" tag to the question.